# ESP32 max input voltage UART

Tags: arduino, esp8266

Before doing any mistake, can you confirm me that it is not possible to connect directly UART pins of Arduino UNO on UART pint of ESP32 ?

I see on the datasheet a voltage of 3.3V. I would like to make communicating both boards by TX/RX pins.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a level converter (also called level shifter) from 3.3V to 5V (and around). These devices are bi-directional.

You connect:

- 3.3V to the LV (Low voltage) pin
- 5V to the HV (High Voltage) pin
- RX of the ESP to A0, A1, A2 or A3, e.g. A0
- TX of the ESP to A0, A1, A2 or A3, e.g. A1
- RX of the Arduino opposite of the TX of the ESP, e.g. B0
- TX of the Arduino opposite of the RX of the ESP, e.g. B1
- Connect the GNDs, for clearity better put them on the same row (ESP next to A4, Arduino next to B4).

See [bi-directionional-logic-level-converter-hookup-guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/bi-directional-logic-level-converter-hookup-guide/all) for more details.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your useful answer ! A bridge with a voltage divider could it be another solution to convert voltage ?

Comment: That will work too, however, I doubt you can make it much smaller (unless you use also SMD components), you can get a cheaper one from AliExpress high likely if cost is an issue. Also if you look at the circuit, a MOSFET is used, which makes the low/high voltage completely independent from each other.

Comment: Actually, even a divider made of through hole resistors would be smaller than the usually sold 4-channel MOSFET boards... and a lot more likely to be sourceable without placing a new parts order by an experimentor.  And it's worth keeping in mind that these MOSFET boards usually rely on a 10K pullup, so they are only more firm in driving low, not high.  While they can be used in some UART applications, their real reason for existence is I2C.

Comment: Thank you both of you for your help ! It is really helpful.

Comment: one more thing: Arduino reads 3.3 V as HIGH. so only the RX of esp needs protection by logic level conversion from 5 V of Uno to 3.3 V of esp

Comment: Thank you @Juraj for your comment, it tells me that I can use a simple voltage divider from Arduino's TX pin to ESP's RX pin.

Answer (score 0):

Arduino with 5 V AVR MCU reads 3.3 V as HIGH. But the RX of the 3.3 V MCU's RX pin could be damaged by 5 V TX of the 5 V MCU. A voltage divider will do it.